# Select all of attribute values from database Entity Framework C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

I want to get all values of an attribute and put it in a list

Something look like below code:

```
List<int> X_Positions = _Context.ParkingPlaces.Where(e => e.X_position).All();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of *filtering* with [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040(v=vs.110).aspx) you should use *projection* with [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548743(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
List<int> X_Positions = _Context.ParkingPlaces.Select(e => e.X_position).ToList();
```

Also, there is no parameterless `All()` operator. There is [`All(predicate)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534754(v=vs.110).aspx) operator, which is used to check whether all items in source sequence satisfy some condition. Note that filtering also requires a predicate - function which returns a boolean value to filter out items which do not match the predicate.